# IllegalStateException: please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to implement Kafka producer which sends and receives Java Serialized Objects. I tried this:

***Producer:***

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

@Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
private String bootstrapAddress;

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleRequestFactorySerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}


@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory());
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

}

***Send object:***

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate;

private static String topic = "tp-sale";

private void perform(){

    SaleRequestFactory obj = new SaleRequestFactory();
    obj.setId(100);

    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, SaleRequestFactory>> send = saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate.send(topic, obj);
}
```

***Consumer:***

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    private String groupId = "test";

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleResponseFactoryDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

***Receive Object***

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "tp-sale")
public SaleResponseFactory transactionElavonAuthorizeProcess(@Payload SaleRequestFactory tf, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(tf.getId());

    SaleResponseFactory resObj = new SaleResponseFactory();
    resObj.setUnique_id("123123");

    return resObj;
}
```

***Custom objects***

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    public class SaleRequestFactory implements Serializable{
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;
        
        private int id;
    }

public class SaleRequestFactorySerializer implements Serializable, Serializer<SaleRequestFactory> {

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, SaleRequestFactory data) {
        // convert data to byte[]
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
            outputStream.writeObject(data);
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}


    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    public class SaleResponseFactory implements Serializable{
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;
    
        private String unique_id;
    }

public class SaleResponseFactoryDeserializer implements Serializable, Deserializer<SaleResponseFactory> {

    @Override
    public SaleResponseFactory deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        // convert data to SaleResponseFactory
        SaleResponseFactory saleResponseFactory = null;
        try
        {
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            saleResponseFactory = (SaleResponseFactory) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return saleResponseFactory;
    }
}
```

When I try to send message I get error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition tp-sale-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: null
21:27:51.152 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] DEBUG KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer[debug:296] - Commit list: {}
21:27:51.153 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] ERROR KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer[error:149] - Consumer exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This error handler cannot process 'SerializationException's directly; please consider configuring an 'ErrorHandlingDeserializer' in the value and/or key deserializer
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekUtils.seekOrRecover(SeekUtils.java:145)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.handle(SeekToCurrentErrorHandler.java:103)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.handleConsumerException(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1265)
        at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1022)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition tp-sale-0 at offset 0. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: null
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

***EDIT:***
I managed to implement these improvements:

***Producer:***

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

@Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
private String bootstrapAddress;

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleRequestFactorySerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}


@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory());
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
}
```

}

***Send object:***

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate;

private static String topic = "tp-sale";

private void perform(){

    SaleRequestFactory obj = new SaleRequestFactory();
    obj.setId(100);

    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, SaleRequestFactory>> send = saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate.send(topic, obj);
}
```

***Consumer:***

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    private String groupId = "test";

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleResponseFactoryDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

***Receive Object***

```
    @KafkaListener(topics = "tp-sale")
public SaleResponseFactory transactionElavonAuthorizeProcess(@Payload SaleRequestFactory tf, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) throws Exception {

    System.out.println(tf.getId());

    SaleResponseFactory resObj = new SaleResponseFactory();
    resObj.setUnique_id("123123");

    return resObj;
}
```

***Custom objects***

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    public class SaleRequestFactory implements Serializable{
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;
        
        private int id;
    }

public class SaleRequestFactorySerializer implements Serializable, Serializer<SaleRequestFactory> {

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, SaleRequestFactory data) {
        // convert data to byte[]
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
            outputStream.writeObject(data);
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}


    @Getter
    @Setter
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder(toBuilder = true)
    public class SaleResponseFactory implements Serializable{
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;
    
        private String unique_id;
    }

public class SaleResponseFactoryDeserializer implements Serializable, Deserializer<SaleResponseFactory> {

    @Override
    public SaleResponseFactory deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        // convert data to SaleResponseFactory
        SaleResponseFactory saleResponseFactory = null;
        try
        {
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            saleResponseFactory = (SaleResponseFactory) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return saleResponseFactory;
    }
}
```

When I send some message I get error:

```
13:03:53.675 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] DEBUG RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter[debug:296] - Listener method returned result [org.factory.SaleResponseFactory@69c400ab] - generating response message for it
13:03:53.675 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] DEBUG RecordMessagingMessageListenerAdapter[debug:296] - No replyTopic to handle the reply: org.factory.SaleResponseFactory@69c400ab
```

Do you know how I can return `SaleResponseFactory` back to the original Producer class?

EDIT 2:
I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer<java.lang.String, org.engine.plugin.transactions.factory.SaleResponseFactory>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1717)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've correctly configured server side for request reply you can use `ReplyingKafkaTemplate` to receive the reply message on the client side.

Something like

Replying Producer Config

```
@Configuration
@Import({KafkaProducerConfig.class, KafkaConsumerConfig.class})
public class ReplyingKafkaProducerConfig {

  @Bean
  public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory, SaleResponseFactory> replyKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, SaleRequestFactory> producerFactory, ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> factory) {
     ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, SaleResponseFactory> container = factory.createContainer("tp-sale");       
     container.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("tp-sale.reply");
     return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory, container);
  }   

}
```

Replying Template

```
@Autowired
private ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory, SaleResponseFactory> requestReplyKafkaTemplate;

private static String topic = "tp-sale";

private void perform(){

  SaleRequestFactory obj = new SaleRequestFactory();
  obj.setId(100);   
  ProducerRecord<String, SaleRequestFactory> record = new ProducerRecord<>("tp-sale", obj);
  RequestReplyFuture<String, SaleRequestFactory, SaleResponseFactory> replyFuture = requestReplyKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);
  SendResult<String, SaleRequestFactory> sendResult = replyFuture.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  ConsumerRecord<String, SaleResponseFactory> consumerRecord = replyFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}
```

Example borrowed from https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#replying-template

Comment: Can you please add example for `ReplyingKafkaTemplate`?

Comment: Added.Thank you. Please note if you are using java ser/deser you will need to use same object ( in other words you can't have different object for request and response). You may want to look into json ser/deser for such case. Other thing you can't have same reply and request topic.

Comment: Unfortunately I get error during startup. See Edit 2.

Comment: Now I get `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No group.id found in consumer config, container properties, or @KafkaListener annotation; a group.id is required when group management is used.`

Comment: Sorry, obviously I've added answer based on docs without any testing. Please add the group id as reported. I'll try to set up something at my end.  Updated answer.

Comment: Now I get `
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.engine.plugin.transactions.factory.SaleResponseFactory (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.engine.plugin.transactions.factory.SaleResponseFactory is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @6267c3bb)`

Comment: Any idea why I get this issue?

Comment: Could you share the configuration for the reply template from the server side ? I also dont see the @Send annotation anywhere. Please update the post to reflect server side configuration. Your server side consumer factory should be configured with reply kafka template with producer factory capable of handling serializing `SaleResponseFactory` payload ( means configured with custom serializer - in essence `SaleResponseFactorySerializer` )

Comment: Here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64961034/classcastexception-class-java-lang-string-cannot-be-cast-to-class-saleresponsef  But I have one idea why it's not working here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64977248/implement-factory-pattern-for-kafka-consumer

Comment: I think your answer lies in correct server side configuration with consumer factory ( must have reply kafka template configured which is backed by producer factory capable for serializing `SaleResponseFactory` payload ). There are pairs of ser/deser , `SaleRequestFactorySerializer` to send the request and  `SaleResponseFactoryDeSerializer`  to receive the reply on the client side. Similarly on the server side you will have `SaleRequestFactoryDeSerializer` to receive the request and `SaleResponseFactorySerializer` to send the reply. I didn't find those details in the linked question. Share pls?

Comment: The files `SaleRequestFactory`, `SaleRequestFactorySerializer`, `SaleResponseFactory` and `SaleResponseFactoryDeserializer` are located into `plugin.jar`. This jar is compiled using `clean package` and `clean install` and after that pasted into lib folder of the  consumer/producer. So the files are the same everywhere.

Comment: Wha about other pair ? `SaleRequestFactoryDeser` for receiving request and `SaleResponseFactorySer` for sending reply.

Comment: Can I create a simple proof of a concept and give you the code to test it locally?

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/rcbandit111/kafka_test Please ask me if you're stucked with something.

Comment: Thank you - I've a working example - Can you allow me to push to your repo ? I will submit the PR

Comment: Sure, Github account?

Comment: Please check your e-mail.

Comment: Thanks - https://github.com/rcbandit111/kafka_test/pull/1

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working fine. Can I ask one additional question, please? I'm thinking to use Apache Streams to implement code with low latency and height performance. Have you tried it? Also into the current code how performance can be increased?

Answer (score 1):

See [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.6.2/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer).

> Using `ErrorHandlingDeserializer`

> When a deserializer fails to deserialize a message, Spring has no way to handle the problem, because it occurs before the poll() returns. To solve this problem, the `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` has been introduced. This deserializer delegates to a real deserializer (key or value). If the delegate fails to deserialize the record content, the ErrorHandlingDeserializer returns a null value and a DeserializationException in a header that contains the cause and the raw bytes. When you use a record-level `MessageListener`, if the `ConsumerRecord` contains a `DeserializationException` header for either the key or value, the container’s ErrorHandler is called with the failed ConsumerRecord. The record is not passed to the listener.

> ...