# ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class SaleResponseFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to implement Kafka Consumer and Producer which sends and receives Java Objects. Full [Source](https://github.com/rcbandit111/kafka_test) I tried this:

***Producer:***

```
    @Configuration
public class KafkaProducerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleRequestFactorySerializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
    }


    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(saleRequestFactoryProducerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory, SaleResponseFactory> replyKafkaTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, SaleRequestFactory> producerFactory, ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> factory) {
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, SaleResponseFactory> kafkaMessageListenerContainer = factory.createContainer("tp-sale");
        kafkaMessageListenerContainer.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("tp-sale.reply");
        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory, kafkaMessageListenerContainer);
    }
}
```

***Send object:***

```
 @RestController
@RequestMapping("/checkout")
public class CheckoutController {
    
    private TransactionService transactionService;
    private KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate;
    private ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory, SaleResponseFactory> requestReplyKafkaTemplate;
    private static String topic = "tp-sale";

    @Autowired
    public CheckoutController(ValidationMessage validationMessage, TransactionService transactionService,
                              KafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory> saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate,
                              ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, SaleRequestFactory, SaleResponseFactory> requestReplyKafkaTemplate){
        this.transactionService = transactionService;
        this.saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate = saleRequestFactoryKafkaTemplate;
        this.requestReplyKafkaTemplate = requestReplyKafkaTemplate;
    }

    @PostMapping("test")
    private void performPayment() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {

        Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
        transaction.setStatus(PaymentTransactionStatus.IN_PROGRESS.getText());

        Transaction insertedTransaction = transactionService.save(transaction);

        SaleRequestFactory obj = new SaleRequestFactory();
        obj.setId(100);

        ProducerRecord<String, SaleRequestFactory> record = new ProducerRecord<>("tp-sale", obj);
        RequestReplyFuture<String, SaleRequestFactory, SaleResponseFactory> replyFuture = requestReplyKafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);
        SendResult<String, SaleRequestFactory> sendResult = replyFuture.getSendFuture().get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        ConsumerRecord<String, SaleResponseFactory> consumerRecord = replyFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


        SaleResponseFactory value = consumerRecord.value();
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!! " + value.getUnique_id());
    }
}
```

***Consumer:***

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

    @Value(value = "${kafka.bootstrapAddress}")
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    private String groupId = "test";

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, SaleResponseFactoryDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, SaleResponseFactory> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

***Receive Object***

```
@Component
public class ProcessingSaleListener {

    private static String topic = "tp-sale";

    @KafkaListener(topics = "tp-sale")
    public SaleResponseFactory process(@Payload SaleRequestFactory tf, @Headers MessageHeaders headers) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(tf.getId());

        SaleResponseFactory resObj = new SaleResponseFactory();
        resObj.setUnique_id("123123");

        return resObj;
    }
}
```

***Custom objects***

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class SaleRequestFactory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;
    
    private int id;

}
```

***Serializer***

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SaleRequestFactorySerializer implements Serializable, Serializer<SaleRequestFactory> {

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, SaleRequestFactory data)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
            outputStream.writeObject(data);
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled", e);
        }
        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

***Response Object***

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
public class SaleResponseFactory implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1744050117179344127L;

    private String unique_id;
}
```

***Response Class***

```
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SaleResponseFactoryDeserializer implements Serializable, Deserializer<SaleRequestFactory> {

    @Override
    public SaleRequestFactory deserialize(String topic, byte[] data)
    {
        SaleRequestFactory saleRequestFactory = null;
        try
        {
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            saleRequestFactory = (SaleRequestFactory) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled", e);
        }
        return saleRequestFactory;
    }
}
```

When I send some message I get error:

```
23:52:08.920 [consumer-0-C-1] DEBUG KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer[debug:313] - Commit list: {tp-sale-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=35, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}
23:52:08.920 [consumer-0-C-1] DEBUG KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer[debug:313] - Committing: {tp-sale-0=OffsetAndMetadata{offset=35, leaderEpoch=null, metadata=''}}
23:52:08.926 [http-nio-8090-exec-4] DEBUG OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor[afterCompletion:111] - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
23:52:08.928 [http-nio-8090-exec-4] DEBUG DispatcherServlet[logResult:1101] - Failed to complete request: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.engine.plugin.transactions.factory.SaleResponseFactory (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.engine.plugin.transactions.factory.SaleResponseFactory is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @6267c3bb)
23:52:08.928 [http-nio-8090-exec-4] DEBUG HstsHeaderWriter[writeHeaders:169] - Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@2cfd2bb6
23:52:08.928 [http-nio-8090-exec-4] DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository[saveContext:351] - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
23:52:08.928 [http-nio-8090-exec-4] DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter[doFilter:119] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
23:52:08.929 [http-nio-8090-exec-4] ERROR [dispatcherServlet][log:175] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/engine] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.engine.plugin.transactions.factory.SaleResponseFactory (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.engine.plugin.transactions.factory.SaleResponseFactory is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @6267c3bb)] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.engine.plugin.transactions.factory.SaleResponseFactory (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.engine.plugin.transactions.factory.SaleResponseFactory is in unnamed module of loader org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader @6267c3bb)
        at org.engine.rest.CheckoutController.performPayment(CheckoutController.java:95)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:158)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:92)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

Do you know how I can fix this issue?

Comment: Please show `CheckoutController.performPayment`

Comment: I updated the producer code.

Comment: It looks like Boot's default `StringDeserializer` is being used on the sending side (for the reply) instead of your custom deserializer.  Your configuration is not clear; you don't show the consumer factorty on the sending side; you show one on the consumer side (but that deserializes a reply not a request. Show all of your configuration and application properties; and make it clear which applies to which side.

Comment: Hello Gary. I have update the post. I get the exception at this line `SaleResponseFactory value = consumerRecord.value();`

Comment: You serialize a request and deserialize a response?

Comment: hm... good question. What is the proper process for this case?