# Implement Factory pattern for Kafka consumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to get response object from Kafka consumer. Full [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64961034/classcastexception-class-java-lang-string-cannot-be-cast-to-class-saleresponsef)
In my case as you can see I'm casting input to a factory object instead of using the factory object to transform the input into custom object.

```
    ConsumerRecord<String, SaleResponseFactory> consumerRecord = replyFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    SaleResponseFactory value = (SaleResponseFactory) consumerRecord.value();
    System.out.println("!!! " + value.getUnique_id());
```

It's not very clear for me how I can use the factory pattern in this case. Is there some better solution in general?

Answer (score 0):

This should just work out of the box with the Kafka consumer API and an appropriate deserializer; no casting required since you're using generics `ConsumerRecord<String, SaleResponseFactory>`

Factory pattern is for building objects. All you're doing here is accessing a method of a Kafka event that's already been deserialized and built